# How to resolve endpoint for an Android app aimed at multiple customers?

Tags: single-sign-on

First let me explain the problem:

We have an Android app and multiple customers. Each customer has their own endpoint (Kubernetes cluster of microservices basically) that the app should communicate with. To prevent us from having to deploy multiple versions of the app (one for each customer) we are looking for a solution that will use one app but allow for multiple endpoints.

I am interested in knowing if, and if so how, others have solved this.

We have tried:

- Automatic endpoint resolution within the app based on user's domain. This fails our requirements because we then need to build a new app for every customer, which is not optimal with 10's of customers appearing every week.
- Microservice that gives the user and endpoint based on user's domain. This fails because it creates a Catch 22 problem... how do we know the endpoint to this microservice?
- Keycloak User Attributes. We use Keycloak for SSO. Using the REST API in Keycloak requires an admin user, but we do not want to expose such an admin user from any external application.
- Manual endpoint insertion in the app. Highly user-unfriendly!

Comment: don't think you should tag this with `android`, pretty irrelevant i'd say whether this was for android or ios, but rather update your tags to include `Kubernetes` and the actual technologies you're looking for, but your question might be too broad for SO

Comment: Maybe you can add more details to your question? For me it's not clear role of the kubernetes. Just mentioned as endpoints for customers. How it should work at all?